# Открыть контекстное меню там, где курсор мыши

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/coolerprinter/xg10vzeL/

Как открыть свое контекстное меню там, где находится курсор мыши?
К примеру, такой код не работает:

```
$("body").on("contextmenu", function(e){
     var x = function(e) { return e.pageX };
     var y = function(e) { return e.pageY };
  $(".contextmenu").css({
      "left": x,
      "top": y,
      "display":"block"
});
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: Во-первых потому, что в функции нет принимающего параметра `e`. Должно быть ` function(e){`  а во вторых, если нет элементов на странице, то, возможно, высота `body` будет нулевая.... и конечно никуда не попадете... да еще  и return `e.pageX` не в том контексте

Comment: Забыл параметр **е** написать. BODY не пустой.

Comment: `BODY не пустой`..... и есть гарантия? Ну тогда  логично что `e.pageX` не к той функции относится, правда?  https://jsfiddle.net/zfsc0prb/2/

Comment: Спасибо! Обьясните, пожалуйста, почему 1 способ не работает?

Comment: 1 способ это какой? Ваш? Потому, что у вас `x` и `y`, по сути - вы пока объявили функции (а не поля или свойства), принимающие один параметр на вход. Это только объявление.. а надо их вызывать.. так: `x()` или `y()` ...передав на вход параметр... то есть `x(e)` или `y(e)`...Поэтому вот это `function(e) { return e.pageX }` по факту это вы не передаете переменную внешнюю, а просто объявили функцию, которая будет принимать на вход параметр с именем `e` ...использовать в вашем случае можно вот так: `var x = function(e) { return e.pageX }(e);` с игриком также ... это 3 способ

Answer (score 4):

Прежде всего, Ваш jsfiddle не работает, потому что не загружен jQuery. Щелкните на Javascript в правом верхнем углу скриптового участка и выберите какую-нибудь версию jQuery.

Следующая проблема, как уже объяснил Алексей Шиманский, - это путаница с параметрами функций, присвоенных переменным `x` и `y`. Как указано в http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function, параметрами в эти функции будут поданы порядковый номер DOM элемента в наборе элементов, определенных селектором (в данном случае - `".contextmenu"`), и старое значение свойства css. Контекст `this` - сам DOM элемент. Так как эти параметры Вы не используете, их можно не указывать.

Ну и чтобы обработчик `contextmenu` вызывался при щелчке в любом месте страницы, используйте `html` вместо `body`.

```
$("html").contextmenu(function(e){
  var x = function(index, value) { return e.pageX };
  var y = function(index, value) { return e.pageY };
  $(".contextmenu").css({
    "left": x,
    "top": y,
    "display":"block"
  });
  return false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xg10vzeL/6/

Более простой вариант, где значения `left` и `top` назначаются без использования функций:

```
$("html").contextmenu(function(e){
  $(".contextmenu").css({
    "left": e.pageX,
    "top": e.pageY,
    "display":"block"
  });
  return false;
});
```